# Exit command mode in sublime text 2

Tags: text-editor, sublimetext2

I just started using sublime text 2 and when I go into command mode I can't get out.

How do I exit out?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

<kbd>Escape</kbd> puts you into command mode; `i` takes you back out.

Comment: It's rather _i_ that puts you into insert mode, and _Escape_ that takes you back out.

Comment: @BrunoParmentier then they cannot use i for the for loop?

Comment: If `i` is not applicable then press `Escape` once and then press `i`. Its worked like charm. Thanks for the info, very useful.

Answer (score 79):

... And, if you want to avoid entering in the command mod when pressing ESC key, add the following ignored packages in your sublime preferences:

```
"ignored_packages":
[
    "Vintage"
]
```

Comment: thanks, this was driving me nuts...I must've inadvertently removed that package from the ignore list at some point cos it started happening all of a sudden

Comment: Yah, it has started happening to me all of a sudden as well. Wondering if there was an update that changed this behavior.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like by default in Preferences > Settings - Default
this is enabled

```
"ignored_packages": ["Vintage"]
```

but then it's overwritten in Settings - User by

```
"ignored_packages": [
]
```

so copy the setting from Settings - Default to Settings - User
That worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

As in Vim, to exit the command mode, press <kbd>i</kbd> `insert` to keep the cursor exactly where it is positioned.

But, since it requires a lot of hand-movements, I personally hate pressing <kbd>i</kbd> everytime.

So, while fiddling around with Sublime, I found that pressing <kbd>a</kbd> also took you back into normal mode, although the cursor advances by one character (`append` as correctly pointed out by Chris), I think I'll take that over `i`.

So, <kbd>ESC</kbd> to enter, <kbd>a</kbd> to exit the command mode.

Comment: 'a' would be for append - much like VI

Comment: I prefer using `a` because it's faster to do with your left hand only and not have to 'travel' across the keyboard to hit the `i`.

Comment: yup, exactly my reason.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Escape key or Ctrl/Command + ~ (tilde)

Comment: I had a shortcut and esc wasn't working but I accidentally pressed 'i' and that took me back to insert mode. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [Mr Washington's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22037138/3502104):

Note that you can't simply remove the `"ignored_packages"` section in the user preferences as it will be added back on the next startup of sublime. Overwriting it is required.